# ClassNotFoundException for main-class running an executable jar with dependencies

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I cannot find the issue here:

I created a jar using a maven plugin, but the dog won't hunt.

The class:

```
package com.foo.baitshop;

public class Design {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        int argLength = args.length;
    }
}
```

I unzipped the jar to peek inside and the META-INF folder is in the root and contains the manifest (MANIFEST.MF).

It looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: lwhite
Build-Jdk: 9.0.4
Main-Class: com.foo.baitshop.Design;
```

To Run, i execute the following in the directory holding the jar:

`java -jar baitshop2-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

There is no classpath set externally in this environment.

The error message is:

```
fm-mltp140:target lwhite$ java -jar baitshop2-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class com.foo.baitshop.Design;
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/foo/baitshop/Design;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the semi-colon:

```
Main-Class: com.foo.baitshop.Design;
```

It needs to be removed to be:

```
Main-Class: com.foo.baitshop.Design
```

If Maven is generating this, the Maven configuration needs to be debugged to prevent adding the semi-colon. Likely there is a semi-colon in the configuration somewhere.

The associated [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) from Oracle.

Comment: It's possible that that is correct, but the semicolon was added by maven. the source manifest was:  Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.foo.baitshop.Design

Comment: Can you show the maven configuration for this from your pom? I don't think maven should be adding that, and I suspect a typo in a configuration somewhere.

Comment: No worries, I'll update my answer to take Maven into account better.